# How to change user group cover image

Tags: facebook

How can I change group cover image via graph API? Can anyone help me please?

I implemented this but it is not working.

```
$cover_url = "test.jpg";

$response = $this->_facebook->api('/group_id', "POST", array ( 'access_token' => $app_token,'cover_url' => $cover_url));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be more specific about "Not working". What does it mean? What error do you get?

From the [Official GRAPH API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group):
**An app that created an app or game group can update that groups cover photo.**

Guessing that you do not qualify for this rule because you're trying to change user group cover photo.

Comment: What does it mean, "An app that created an app or game group"??

Comment: That means, that an app can only change cover picture for app and game groups it has created itself and as this doesn't mention anything about user groups, then you can assume it's not possible to use Graph API to change user group cover image.

Comment: Ok, means we can only change cover image of a group which is created by graph api. Right?

Comment: No. Means that you can only change **APP** and **GAME** group covers which is made by the APP. It does not say it has to be done through Graph API.